# Spring Data Cassandra: Run WHERE only if param not null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

As you know, you can do something like this in Spring Cassandra:

```
@Query("SELECT * from Report WHERE :param1 = "test")
List<Report> findByParam1(@Param String param1);
```

But what if Param1 is null? I want to create a query where the "WHERE" clause gets ignored if there is no param1 to check. Is something like this in CASSANDRA possible?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking is not directly possible. But you can achieve the same by creating another method findAll method with no param and call it when the param is null.

example

```
@Query("SELECT * from Report WHERE :param1 = "test")
List<Report> findByParam1(@Param String param1);

@Query("SELECT * from Report")
List<Report> findAll();
```

Now based your check of is param null, you can either call `findByParam1(param)` or `findAll()` method.